# How do I collapse an expanded column into single rows?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint list containing a column with data type `People or Group` which can contain multiple people. When this list is imported into Power BI it appears as `[Table]` in the Power BI Query Editor.

[image]

When I expand this column (using highlighted button above), it creates multiple rows (which I don't want).

My goal is to preserve the row count of my table by converting all duplicate rows created by the expansion back to single rows with a delimiter between values. Has anyone found a way to consolidate this?

#### Data example

Original Data

| ID | ColumnHeader | OtherColumns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [Table] | OtherData |

After expansion

| ID | ColumnHeader | OtherColumns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FakeEmail@email.com | OtherData |
| 1 | FakeEmail2@email.com | OtherData |

Target output

| ID | ColumnHeader | OtherColumns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FakeEmail@email.com# FakeEmail2@email.com | OtherData |

*The delimiter can be anything (not neccesarily a #)

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do what you want but it will be difficult for anyone to help without seeing input data and expected output. Can you show the columns that get expanded and how you want these to be reaggregated if there are multiple rows.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for pointing that out @David. I've added an example

Comment: OK, understood. I'll add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have a table like this.

[image]

Table (in green) contains data structured like this.

[image]

To achieve the concatenation you're after as follows:

[image]

Add a custom column with the following code.

```
Text.Combine([ColumnHeader][Column Header A],"# ")
```